# IRS2336 inverter shutting off at low frequencies

Tags: h-bridge, stepper-driver

I am currently working on a project where the core is controlling a hybrid stepper motor. Unfortunately I am having issues with controlling the current properly to in turn control the stepper motor.

I can start with showing the problem, as someone might find clues or at least tips of what can be wrong from seeing that! and then walk through the setup later.

So what happens is that the current supplied is abrubtly shutting off from the inverters I have controlling the two phases of the motor. And it only happens at lower frequencies. This is how it looks like when running the motor slowly (5 rpm):

[image: Current measurements being done on both phases at 5 rpm]

(This is just an open loop speed control running fixed sinusoidals through both phases with 90 degrees phase shift)

On the contrary when running the motor at higher speeds 15-200 rpm the current gets supplied just fine no problems:

[image: [Current measurements being done on both phases at 5 rpm [2]]

So, as to the setup, both phases are driven by an individual [IRS2336 inverter chip](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irs2336.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567ab2a0280e)

which are driving some [Si7148DP mosfets](http://www.vishay.com/docs/73314/73314.pdf) in a H-bridge setup.

The current is measured by an ADC and sent with SPI to the host, which is a FPGA realtime setup.

As far as the schematic of the full inverter solution, it is not something I've designed, but rather inherited with the project and I have looked at the schematic and it seems to comply with the data sheet of the IRS2336. And seeing the solution works flawlessly at higher frequencies (and both higher and lower amplitudes of current) I don't feel that's where the issue lies.

For me it feels non intuitive that there is more problems with changing the current slowly than it is to change it more rapidly! (for the actual hardware that is at least).

What I have done so far to try understanding the problem:

- Measured the true current draw with an oscilloscope in the phases, and the current measurement is working correctly, the readings are true.
- Checked the FAULT signal that is integrated in the IRS2336 chip, and it is staying high, so it doesnt seem to be that the inverter chip that actually shuts off.

So maybe there is something wrong with the controlling of the actual IRS2336 chip? At this moment I don't have access to the code controlling that but I might have to try find it the coming days.

My first intention was to put this up here and see if someone has encountered something similar before when dealing with inverters/H-bridge drivers and have  ideas on what might be the issue!

Thankful for any advice,

Best regards, Mattias

Answer (score 1):

Your "inverter chip" (really just a set of low-side and high-side MOSFET gate drivers) uses a "bootstrap" circuit in order to generate the boosted voltage (higher than the supply by at least V<sub>GS</sub>) required for N-channel MOSFETs. This circuit has a minimum operating frequency, set in part by the value of the boost capacitor connected between each HO*n* pin and the corresponding VB*n* pin.

The general idea is that you should use a fixed, relatively high-frequency PWM signal to drive the MOSFET gates, and this frequency is high enough to keep the boost supply charged up. If you are simply driving the gates with the motor waveform directly (without PWM) — or if your PWM frequency is varying with the motor speed — at low speeds, the boost supply will droop and the high-side transistor will cut off.

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for your reply. The chip is indeed run with a 20kHz PWM from the FPGA that is supposed to send the on/off commands for the mosfets. And the cap between HOn and VBn is 1uF.

The problem is I am not sitting on the code that is producing these PWMs at this moment, so I can't really know if the fault is in there...

Something I fear kind of makes the question very limited. I really have to get my hands on that FPGA code I reckon..

Comment: If you can't change the drive signals, then you'll have to provide the boosted voltage by some other means. Unfortunately, this will probably require a separate DC-DC converter for each output channel, since each VB*n* needs to "float" relative to its HO*n*. Perhaps increasing the boost capacitors to, say, 10 uF (or more) will be enough.

Comment: I think I can be able to change the drive signals eventually, but going to need help programming the FPGA (from al person external from the project). But are you suggesting to increase the frequency of the controlling PWMs? I am not really sure I understand why that would help? 

Because the pwm signal controls how long to keep the H-bridge open to supply the current requested. And seeing the frequency of this PWM is fixed what changes is the duty cycle? I don't understand why the slower motor frequency would be a problem? Is it because it is trying to keep the gate open for longer?

Comment: My answer is just an educated guess based on the limited information you've provided so far. It would be pointless to speculate further until we both know what the drive signal actually looks like.

Comment: Yes, I understand Dave, was just trying to understand your idea  a bit better (as I am not very used to inverters or drivers in general). Thank you for your input, I will try to find and debug the actual control for the inverter aswell and might update the question and ping you then.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be running a motor at two different frequencies and expect the current taken to be the same. I'm not sure if this is your problem but it sounds to me like the same sort of issue that arises when using a variable speed drive on an induction motor. Below a certain speed threshold the voltage amplitude has to fall linearly with frequency or the core of the motor will saturate and you will get current limit problems.

If I've misread your question, let me know and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It's a stepper motor, and the idea is to run position control? So ideally I would want the drive to supply any current I would want it to (or possibly very low amplitude, low frequency currents). But I have never worked with inverters before, so you are telling me that this premise is impossible? As I said I have "inherited" the driver board and it is set up "for me" by the project leader or w/e. I am mainly troubleshooting why the current is shutting off.

Can you elaborate a little on the last part? Why does it have to fall linearly, what do you mean with the core of the motor saturating?

Comment: Try looking up induction motor speed control and v to f ratio especially at low speeds.

Comment: Hmm I have skimmed through some articles and not sure I understand fully. But do you usually run variable voltage control when you do control on induction motors?

Because I run with fixed voltage, just changing the pwm duty cycle to produce different currents..

Comment: VFDs nearly always lower the voltage drive when frequency drops a little below rated operating frequency. The stator is an inductor after all and at half the frequency it will consume twice the magnetisation current and be twice as emerged into core saturation.

Comment: I am running it on a hybrid stepper motor ? With a permanent magnet rotor I am not sure that's exactly what you are thinking about?

Comment: It's certainly not an induction motor but it has stator coils that can saturate. What does the motor data sheet say about variable frequency control?